# How to get Datepicker Textbox enterkey event handler

Tags: wpf, datepicker, wpf-controls

is anybody tell me how can we create datepicker textbox enterkey event? please guild me about this technique.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally on this website, we like questions to be more detailed than yours, but if you do just want to handle when the `Enter` key is pressed in a `DatePicker` control, then you can do that using the [`Keyboard.PreviewKeyUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.previewkeyup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attached event:

The XAML:

```
<DatePicker Keyboard.PreviewKeyUp="DatePicker_PreviewKeyUp" />
```

And the handler:

```
private void DatePicker_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // The Enter key was pressed
    }
}
```

I would like to point out that this is *not* the same as using the [`DatePicker.SelectedDateChanged` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddatechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is raised whenever the selected date is changed using any means.